# Armazenar os positivos em um vetor e os negativos em outro

Tags: c, array, lógica

> Faça um algoritmo que leia um conjunto de 30 valores numéricos inteiros e distribua-os entre dois vetores, separando os números positivos dos negativos. Os vetores devem ter 30 posições cada. Mostre os vetores ao final do processamento.

```
int vetPos[3], vetNeg[3];
int valor, i, cont;
cont = 1;

do{
    printf("Informe um valor: ");
    scanf("%d",&valor);

    if(valor >= 0){
        //insere no vetor positivo
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            vetPos[i] = valor;
        }            
    }else if(valor < 0){
        //insere no vetor negativo
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            vetNeg[i] = valor;
        }
    }
    valor = 0;
    cont++;
}while(cont<=3);


//saida de dados
printf("Os números positivos digitados foram: ");
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    printf("%3d",vetPos[i]);
}
printf("\nOs números negativos digitados foram: ");
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    printf("%3d",vetNeg[i]);
}
```

No `do..while` fiz cont até 3 apenas para os testes.

No compilador o resultado foi esse:

[image: Tela com o erro]

Entendo que esse erro ocorre porque ele precisa de algo como um delimitador para o vetor, mas não tenho certeza se é só isso, o que posso fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É muito mais simples que isto:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int pos[3], neg[3], posCount = 0, negCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        int valor;
        printf("Informe um valor: ");
        scanf("%d", &valor);
        if (valor < 0) neg[negCount++] = valor;
        else pos[posCount++] = valor;
    }
    printf("Os números positivos digitados foram: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < posCount; i++) printf("%d ", pos[i]);
    printf("\nOs números negativos digitados foram: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < negCount; i++) printf("%d ", neg[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/adQ2ND). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wvptapof-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/CountArrayPosNeg.c).

Não faz o menor sentido ter laços para preencher o vetor, o que fará com que todas posições tenham o mesmo valor e só o último valor entrado. Também não faz sentido ter um `else if` quando ele é exatamente o oposto do `if`. Tem variável demais e faltam variáveis para controlar quantos elementos foram inseridos em cada vetor.

Comment: Nossa, esse artificio de usar o incremento dentro da variável de posição eu nem conseguia imaginar, basicamente ele pula pra próxima posição do vetor apenas se a posição em que ele estiver for preenchida, isso vai ser muito útil para outros exercícios que eu não tinha ideia. Muito obrigado.